# How to hide some sub Categories on top menu if user not login

Tags: magento, authentication, show-hide, categories

How to hide some sub Categories on top menu if user not logged in.

I try to use

```
if($session->isLoggedIn()) {
// $CategoryIdtoHide->setIncludeInMenu(0);
}
```

But is error (I try to write code in *header.phtml* for test but did not work)

edit or i can do anything with this code (i use this code in else if login ) 
'$this->drawCustomMenuItem($_category)'

Answer (score -1):

You need to add conditions in `app\code\core\Mage\Page\Block\Html\Topmenu.php`.

Add your custom condition in it before rendering the child category.